# Unable to access VM through SSH via browser

Tags: google-cloud-platform, ssh, google-compute-engine

I'm trying to connect into my VM with SSH via browser, but I'm not able to do it

This is the output I receive in the troubleshoot:

[image]

How can I solve this?

Comment: Do you have a firewall rule for SSH in the VPC where your VM belongs?

Comment: Also, please make sure that you enable OS login by following this document:
https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/oslogin/set-up-oslogin#enable_os_login